# mysql UPDATE query: add a table column with values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

There are 3 columns in the table:

```
id Name   Rating
1  John   0.976
2  Mark   0.500
3  Andrew 0.976
4  Jane   1.000
```

What sql query could be done to create a new `id_new` column to this table so `id_new` actually is the column that has the ordered by `Rating`?

So, the new table would be:

```
new_id id Name     Rating
1       4 Jane     1.000
2       3 Andrew   0.976
3       1 John     0.976
4       2 Mark     0.500
```

You see this table looks like it was sorted desc by `Rating`.

How to do that using mySql query?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort DESC byRating and show the rank of each row in the results? Or how to add a new column ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the structure of your table and add the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `new_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL FIRST;

SET @new_id:=0;
UPDATE 
   table_name
SET 
   new_id = (@new_id := @new_id + 1)
ORDER BY 
   rating DESC;
```

If you don't want to modify the structure and just return a `SELECT` with the new column:

```
SET @new_id:=0;
SELECT
   (@new_id := @new_id + 1) AS new_id,
   id,
   name,
   rating
FROM
   table_name
ORDER BY
    rating DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE_NAME ADD new_id int(6) FIRST;
```